# How to allow editing number on a filled masked text box?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a masked textbox and I want to edit a number on the middle of the textbox changing the number of the right to the number that I typed.

For example:

111.511-1/11

I want to change that number 5 to 9. So I'll type de left arrow until I get near the dot. When I get near the dot and type 9, the number 5 will disappear and the number 9 will appear.

111.911-1/11

I thought that I need to capture the left arrow typing to do that changing. But I dont know how to capture it.

Any code suggestions?

XAML

```
     <TextBox TextChanged="FormataProcesso" KeyDown="NumberOnly"/>
```

C#

```
     private void FormataProcesso(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Regex regex1 = new Regex("[0-9]{4}$");
            Regex regex2 = new Regex("[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{4}$");
                Regex regex3 = new Regex("[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}$");
    }



    if (regex3.IsMatch(process.Text))
                {
                    isValorTratado = true;
                    processo.Text = string.Format("{0}/{1}", process.Text.Substring(0, 9), process.Text.Substring(9, 1));

                    process.SelectionStart = process.Text.Length;
                    process.SelectionLength = 0;
                }
                else if (regex2.IsMatch(process.Text))
                {

                    processo.Text = string.Format("{0}-{1}", process.Text.Substring(0, 7), process.Text.Substring(7, 1));

                    process.SelectionStart = process.Text.Length;
                    process.SelectionLength = 0;
                }


....
```

Comment: Please first show the code you have, what masking you're using, etc.

Comment: And this is how you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your corrections, guys.

I used it:

```
            int position = numProcess.SelectionStart;

            if (numProcess.Text.Length <= position)
            {
               ...
            }
            else
            {
                string firstPiece = numProcess.Text.Substring(0, position);
                string secondPiece = numProcess.Text.Substring(position + 1);

                numProcess.Text = firstPiece + secondPiece ;

                numProcess.SelectionStart = position;
                numProcess.SelectionLength = 0;
            }
```